# Are for... in loops useful in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

I'm new to JavaScript, and I'm currently learning about the so-called `for... in` loop.

Does one actually use those loops when coding in JavaScript?

I can see how all other types of loops are useful — but not this one.

Someone shed some light on this please and include a real life example if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Javascript only Array objects can be iterated with a normal `for(;;)` loop.  The `for..in` is used for enumeration of non-array objects:

```
for (var i in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) { // if you don't want to access prototype properties
        alert(i);
        alert(obj[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Agree about hasOwnProperty(), but you may also want to check typeof() to ensure that function types etc. don't end up in your output.

Comment: @MickSear That entirely depends on what you do with the object. If, for example, you use the traversal for "clone"-ing the object, then you don't really care. Anyway, I've only added it because it's something he might run into, wasn't really related to the question itself.

Comment: Just as a note: my answer is only about general practices and I've ignored some technicalities. `arguments` is an exception to the `only Array objects can be iterated` and of course that `for` loops are only incidentally used for traversing arrays, but I think these things are not really important to the question itself.

Comment: wasn't a criticism, just that I recently read the Douglas Crockford book 'Javascript, The Good Parts' and it came to mind :)

Comment: Any object can be iterated, as long as it has numeric properties and a `length` property. But don't think the OP really needs to learn all that at this stage.

Comment: @NathanMacInnes Of course, but then (generally) why not use an array? That's why I've added my second comment, things can become murky sometimes, but I've tried to describe the general case.

Answer (score 0):

It is typically used to loop over a collection of something. For instance, since every JavaScript object can be treated as a collection of properties, you can enumerate properties in this manner.

```
//let's loop throug all properties of a "document" 
//we don't know what these will be
var txtProps = "";
for (var prop in window.document) {
   txtProps += prop + "\n";
}
alert(txtProps);//pops out a message showing a looong list of all properties
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's OK so long as you understand that an object can hold more than simple variables.  Consider this example, modified from w3schools.com to illustrate the point:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//This is probably as you expect:
var person={fname:"John",lname:"Doe",age:25}; 

//This is probably unexpected and unwanted, but is valid and will be an output of the for...in loop:
person.f = function(){
 alert("Hi");
};

//Use typeof() function to check that the data type is what you expect:
for (x in person){
   document.write(typeof(person[x]) + " ");
}

</script>
```

This prints:

string string number function

To answer your specific question about the differences between loop types, the for() loop works well for array types with a length property.  The foreach() loop can work well for iterating over collections of objects, while the foreach ...in loop works well for keys of an object (Not claiming that these are exclusive uses for any of the loop types).

Answer (score 0):

To understand this, you first need to understand JavaScript's object model.

As you'll have noted, when working with arrays, `for...in` loops aren't that useful because `for (;;)` loops do the job more easily.

But arrays are just a type of JavaScript object with numeric properties, and `for (;;)` loops only handle numeric properties. The reason for the notation `myArray[0]` is that you can use this square bracket notation for any property name. So `myObject['myProperty']` is the same as `myObject.myProperty`. This is where `for...in` becomes useful:

```
for (var i in myObject) {
    alert(myObject[i]);
}
```

So if the only property we'd set was `myProperty`, then `i` would equal `"myProperty"` (note that it's a string, which makes it more dynamic than just being a variable name).

There's a huge BUT here though. Objects have something called a prototype, and these prototypes have their own properties and methods. If I do the following:

```
for (var i in myArray) {
    alert(i + ': ' + myArray[i]);
}
```

...I won't just get alerted with numeric values (1, 2, 3, etc.) I'll also get alerted with the array's properties such as `length`, and its methods such as `join`. These properties actually belong to the Array object's prototype, and the prototype properties can be filtered out by doing the following:

```
for (var i in myArray) {
    if (myArray.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        alert(i + ': ' + myArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Now I'll just get alerted with numeric values again, which means this is (almost) exactly the same as `for (var i = 0;; i < myArray.length; i++)`. Why am I telling you this when we can just use that notation? Because *all* objects have prototypes, not just arrays. And every object descends from the `Object` object, so if somebody defined `Object.prototype.myProperty = "some string value"` then that would always show up in any `for...in` loop you use in the rest of the page. Thankfully, the `hasOwnProperty` method itself belongs to `Object.prototype`, so you can (and should) always use it in your `for...in` loops.

So here's a fully fledged `for...in` example:

```
// This is just one way of defining an object. We could also use a constructor function, or `new Object()`
var myObject = {
    aProperty : "my first property value",
    anotherProperty : "second property value"
    4 : "numeric property names work too, you know"
}

for (var i in myObject) {
    if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
       document.write(i + ': ' + myObject[i] + '<br />\n'); 
    }
}
```

Output:

```
aProperty: my first property value
anotherProperty: secondPropertyValue
4: numeric property names work too, you know
```

Hopefully this explains it all.

Answer (score 0):

Both `for in` and `for` serve specific purposes. Let's look at some.

If you have an **object**

```
var obj = { one: 1, two: 2 };
```

Then you can iterate over it's properties using the `for in` loop i.e

```
for( var i in obj ) console.log( obj[i] );  //use obj.hasOwnProperty(i) to exclude prototype properties
```

note, if you try to iterate `obj` via a for loop it wouldn't work because it would use numeric indexes to access the keys and would give an undefined i.e `obj[0]` would be undefined. This is aside form the fact that getting the length of an object would be more involved than simply writing `obj.length`. Of course if you had numeric properties you would be able to use the `for` loop, `for in` is just a more natural fit for object iteration.

If you have an **array**

```
 var array = [1,2]
```

you could technically use both **but** it's recommended that you use the for loop for this. Here's why

1. The element order is not guaranteed.
2. Prototype properties will also be iterated over, which could cause unwanted side effects.

To illustrate point two, let's extend Array.

```
Array.prototype.print_array = function(){ console.log(this) };
```

This function that we just added to Array will be inherited by all Array objects, hence, iterating over the array via a `for in`

```
for( var i in array ) console.log( array[i] );
```

Would yield

```
1
2
function (){ console.log(this) } // the prototype property was iterated over also
```

And iterating over the array with the `for`

```
for( var i =0; i < array.length; i++) console.log( array[i] );
```

would yield the expected result.

```
1
2
```

Hence, for object iteration use the `for in` and for array iteration use the `for`